# passing variables from a script in the head to a script in the body

Tags: javascript

I have created an HTML document that contains several Javascript scripts. I have created in the head section of the page a Javascript function that generates a specific value. I would like to pass this variable in a Javascript block located in the body section. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's possible; give us an example of what you explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Just make the function in the head global, and call it from the body script. Or call it in the head script and assign the result to a global variable that you access below.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific. 
But this does exactly what you described and it works.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>var test = 'someVar';</script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

alert (test);
</script>
</body>
```